# European week numbers to iOS calendar?

Tags: calendar, ios

I have never really used the calendar in iOS and the below is the reason. I need week numbers for my work, studies, hobbies and almost everything -- that is why I am still using a paper calendar. If a boss gives me a new task, it can be just monday week 33 8PM something -- now I go to paper calendar without touching the phone.

[image]

*Where you can see that adding week numbers preserves every day on the right. Also you need to click to day to see the week number which is outrageously slow.*

If I want to have European week numbers, I need to subscribe to Week Number calendar outlined [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5248859?start=0&tstart=0) and it ruins the availability dots in the calendar like the right. I am looking forward to see week numbers in the month view without preserving every day.

**How can I get the European week numbers to iOS calendar without preserving every day and still being visible in the month view?**

Comment: They're the international standard week numbers, specified by ISO 8601, not "European" week numbers. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

Answer (score 4):

I use [Week Calendar by UtiliTap](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/week-calendar/id381059732?mt=8) instead of the built-in calendar - it's not a free app but it's not expensive and works really well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Starting with iOS 8, there's now a built-in way to show week numbers in the calendar. Go to Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars and scroll down to the Calendars section. Enable Week Numbers and they show up nicely in the built-in calendar app.

[image: calendar screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, in IOS 8.x you may switch on to display week numbers, but you cannot set the ISO (European) counting rule: the first week of the year is the first week, which contains Thursday, whereas US calendars have always 53 weeks, except if the week starts with Sunday. Therefore there may come to a difference of 1 week, which is the case for the year 2016